# Android: soft keyboard either resizes background or hides part of view

Tags: android, android-layout

I know this kind of questions have been asked over and over, but I just can't find a solution to fix my problem and it's driving me crazy.

I have a layout design that has a listview and a edit text inside relative layout. The edit text is at the bottom of the screen and the list view takes up rest of the space.

If I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` in the manifest the background image gets squeezed when soft keyboard shows; if I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan` than the view is pushed up and the action bar and top content of my listview is gone. Neither of these are doing what I want.

When the soft keyboard pops out, I want the action bar and edit text still shows, just like what "adjustResize" does, but at the same time having background image stay fixed (not resized or moved up, but covering bottom of the image).

Other than adjustResize and adjustPan, I also tried setting background programmatically in the code, doing something like `lv.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));` but none works. Can someone please help me with it? Thank you.

p.s. I'm thinking of making a "cut-off" background image, and manually switch to it when keyboard pops out, creating the illusion that it's actually covered. But this seems a bit dumb to me, or is it actually what I'm supposed to do?